# AngularJs bind controller after link append a new element

Tags: angularjs, controller

I have a directive like below, basically append a new element with current one.
and in new element bind ng-controller "openCntl"

```
explorerModule.controller("openCntl",function($scope, $dialog){
    $scope.open = function(){        
        alert('dialog closed with result: ' + result);
    };
});



explorerModule.directive('ngCustomerClick', function($parse){
    return {
        controller :  "openCntl",

        link: function(scope, element, attr){
            var alert = angular.element(
                '<div class="lp-dropdown-wrapper open"  ng-controller="dialogCntl" ' +
                '><div class="arrow"></div>' +
                '<ul class="nav nav-tabs" style="display: inline;">' +
                '<li class="add" ng-click="open()"><a tabindex="-1" href="#"><span class="icon-coffee"></span>Add</a></li>'+
                '</ul></div>'
            );
        }
    }
});
```

but when I click the li, don't invoke the function in the controller "openCntl", how to achieve that?

thanks a lot

Answer (score 7):

You have to use `$compile` to let Angular know about the new element.

the heart of the solution is:

```
link : function(scope, el, attrs) {
  var newElem = angular.element('<SomeNewElement/>');
  el.append(newElem);
  $compile(newElem)(scope); 
}
```

See this plunker that uses a modified version of your code: http://plnkr.co/edit/tOUl8CM56GSd0L3xdNQW?p=preview

Note: in your question, you seem to think that `open` of `openCntl` will be called, but your new element has its own `ng-controller` referring to `dialogCntl`. In your question, `openCntl` is the directive's controller, not the new element's controller. I have also fixed that in my plunker by providing `dialogCntl`.

Comment: yes, you are right, thanks a lot. however  I use another way to achieve that, like add the method into scope , then call it in html